# Удаление нескольких файлов на node js

Tags: node.js, fs

У меня есть список путей к файлу, которые я получаю с базы данных

```
[ { shablon_url: 'uploads\\р-1590038050960.zip' } ]
[ { shablon_url: 'uploads\\р-1590038058494.zip' } ]
```

я записываю их в переменную

var s_rk = spisok.recordset;

и вот функция который я нашел в интернете :

```
    function deleteFiles(files, callback){
        var i = files.length;
        files.forEach(function(filepath){
          fs.unlink(filepath, function(err) {
            i--;
            if (err) {
              callback(err);
              return;
            } else if (i <= 0) {
              callback(null);
            }
          });
        });
      }

      var files = './public/'+s_rk ;

      deleteFiles(files, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('all files removed');
        }
      });
```

И тут выдает ошибку 
TypeError: files.forEach is not a function

Если я указываю пути вручную все ок.
var files = ['uploads\р-1590038050960.zip', 'uploads\р-1590038058494.zip'];

Comment: еще я попытался преобразовать в строку  var files = JSON.stringify(s_rk);

Comment: Чтобы функция работала, параметр `files` должен быть массивом.

Comment: я это понял вот как его преобразовать его вот этого не могу понять